# Upgrade to spring boot 2.0.6.RELEASE makes tests fail even after downgrade to 2.0.5.RELEASE

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle, kotlin

I had on my project tests that were 100% green/OK when using `springBootVersion=2.0.5.RELEASE`.

After I upgraded it to `springBootVersion=2.0.6.RELEASE` some tests failed.
I downgraded it again to `2.0.5.RELEASE` and expected all the tests to be green, but even with `./gradle clean build --no-daemon` the tests continue failing.

What might be wrong?

I'm using openjdk-11 (oracle compile).

My gradle.properties:

```
theSourceCompatibility=1.8
kotlinVersion=1.2.71
springBootVersion=2.0.5.RELEASE
wrapper.gradleVersion=4.10.2
mockkVersion=1.8.9
```

My build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:${kotlinVersion}"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-allopen:${kotlinVersion}"
        classpath 'org.jmailen.gradle:kotlinter-gradle:1.16.0'
        classpath 'org.owasp:dependency-check-gradle:3.3.1'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'kotlin'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-spring'
apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'org.jmailen.kotlinter'
apply plugin: 'org.owasp.dependencycheck'
apply from: 'versioning.gradle'

group = theGroup
version = getGitTag()

apply from: 'docker.gradle'

compileKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}
compileTestKotlin {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = ["-Xjsr305=strict"]
        jvmTarget = "1.8"
    }
}

repositories {
    jcenter()
}


dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
    compile 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect'
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test"
    testCompile "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-test-junit"
    compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin:2.9.3'
    runtime 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    compileOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
    testCompile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testCompile 'org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:1.5.0'
    compile group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents', name: 'httpclient', version: '4.5.6'
    testImplementation "io.mockk:mockk:$mockkVersion"
    //TODO: replace mockk line with the following one when we have kotlin 1.3
    // testCompile "io.mockk:mockk:1.8.9.kotlin13"

    // JUnit 5
    testImplementation("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.2.0")
    testRuntimeOnly("org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.2.0")
    testRuntime("org.junit.platform:junit-platform-console:1.2.0")
}

compileKotlin { dependsOn formatKotlin }
defaultTasks 'clean', 'build'
wrapper { distributionType = Wrapper.DistributionType.ALL }
```

Comment: What were the exceptions in the test failures (after downgrading)? Perhaps there was some dependency mismatch that was not resolved by downgrading - maybe delete the local gradle caches?

Comment: @cjstehno Are the gradlew caches downloaded also into ~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1 folder as it happens for a local gradle installation?

Comment: Check that directory and the `.gradle` directory in the project, if there is one.